# HTML/CSS Gradient link box does not resize

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a link that I would like to appear like a button with a gradient background. This works well when the text is short, but when the text is longer and the screen is made smaller the text wraps and it looks awful. The surrounding "button" box looks like it's been cut off at the end and the wrapped part stuck on below, so it is no longer a single rectangle with curved corners. Instead I would like the background "button" box that to resize and stay rectangular.

```css
.links {
  text-align: center;
}

.links-button {
  border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(81, 195, 247), #0a99db);
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 1px 0;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a class="links-button" href="/example_link">This is a very long link so will wrap when the screen is made smaller</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the default inline styling on the link, use inline-block:

```css
.links {
  text-align: center;
}

.links-button {
  border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(81, 195, 247), #0a99db);
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 1px 0;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a class="links-button" href="/example_link">This is a very long link so will wrap when the screen is made smaller</a>
</div>
```